# Error in Downloading vs 2012 with web platform installer 5.0

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, failed-installation, web-platform-installer

I am trying to download visual studio 2012 with web platform installer 5.0. but it does not install all things and give me error

We're sorry the following product are failed to install.
visual studio 2012 for web(default locale)
This product did not installed successfully.The installation is blocked.

i tried many times but it gives me same error.

Comment: Try installing as administrator?

Comment: yes, i was installing as administrator.

Comment: just to check: did you close VS and SQL management studio? Do you have enough space on disk?

Comment: yes, disk d and e have space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this problem was due to some virus in my computer

**Problem Solved When i tried this:**

1. I Clean my PC with Anti virus
2. Run Ccleaner

After that when i try to Install software i got successful.